# Gauss Divergence Theorem on $z=\sqrt{x^2+y^2-15} 16 \leq x^2+y^2 \leq 40$

Tags: multivariable-calculus, definite-integrals, vector-analysis

Calculate the flow **out** of $(x,y,z)$ through the surface:
$$z=\sqrt{x^2+y^2-15} ,\qquad 16 \leq x^2+y^2 \leq 40$$

To solve this, I tried to apply Gauss Divergence Theorem, I did the following:

First we note that the space is not compact, we solve this by adding a "roof" at z=5 and "flor" at z=1 thus we get the following:
$$\iint_{Y_1}+\iint_{Y_2}+\iint_{Y_3} = \iiint_{D}div(\vec{F})dxdydz$$
Where $Y_2$: $z=1, x^2+y^2 = 16$ and $Y_3: z=5, x^2+y^2=40$.

If I solve these integrals one by one I get:
$$\iint_{Y_2}\vec{F}\cdot \vec{N}dS=\iint_{Y_2}(x,y,1)\cdot(0,0,-1)dS = -\iint_{x^2+y^2\leq16}1dxdy = -16\pi$$
$$\iint_{Y_3}= (x,y,5)\cdot(0,0,1)dS =...=200\pi$$
Using that the normal vector is pointing outwards.

This is where I think I'm messing up, solving the triple integral.
$$\iiint_{D}div(\vec{F})dxdydz = 3\iint_{16\leq x^2
+y^2 \leq 40}(\int_1^{5} dz)dxdy = ...= 288\pi$$

Which would give me the final answear: $\iint_{Y_1}=288\pi+16\pi-200\pi=104\pi$

Which is wrong.

Solving the integrals is fairly simple, where I think I'm wrong is in setting upp the integrals correctly, if someone could point me in the right direction that would be great :)

Thanks in advance

Comment: Your triple integral gives the volume of a cylinder of height $4$ built on top of the annulus $4 < r < \sqrt {40}$. A parametrization for the solid bounded by the hyperboloid is $1 < z < 5 \land 0 < r < \sqrt {z^2 + 15}$.

Comment: Well that solves it.. Thank you :)